# A single command to return control to the parent document

Tags: multiple-files, return

I have a parent document and several "child" documents which I incorporate into the parent document with the `\input` command.

I'd like a single command that would enable me to return to the parent document half way through one of the child documents.

Obviously I can do this with an `\iffalse ... \fi` statement but that's clumsy, would be much nicer to have one command, after all, every other program does.

Here's an MWE.

The parent doc:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{child}
foo
\end{document}
```

The child doc:

```
Hello
World
```

Without using `\iffalse ... \fi`, I'd like to be able to insert a command like \return between Hello and World in the child, forcing an exit and thus producing output  `Hello foo`

~

Comment: I just tested \endinput and it worked (albeit with an extra space).

Comment: `\endinput` is the obvious thing to try. Surprised about the space.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Did you use `Hello\endinput`? That shouldn't insert a space, surely?

Comment: @cfr - No, separate lines.  Wasn't particularly concerned.

Comment: Thanks guys!    `\endinput` worked without any spaces for me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\endinput` stops *at the end of the line*. Therefore if you have something like a `\hspace` after the `\endinput` it will be inserted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{.6em}

\begin{filecontents}{hello.tex}
hello\endinput\hspace{1cm}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{hello-world.tex}
hello \endinput world
earth

universe
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{hello-world-commented.tex}
hello \endinput world%
earth%
%
universe%
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\section{hello}
\input{hello}world

\section{hello-world}
\input{hello-world}\par
\verb|\endinput| stops at the end of the line\ldots

\section{hello-world-commented}
\input{hello-world-commented}\par
\ldots even if the line break is commented out.
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]